# Printing both success and failed message to output file, errorhandler comes too late?

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing, error-handling

I have made some code in VBA to import linked tables into MS-Access. When a table is succesfully added, this should be printed to an output file. When an error occurs, this should be stated instead in the output file. The current output of my code returns both succes and failed line for a table that has an error when added. What do I need to change in the code to only show the succes OR failed line in the output file?

```
Sub CallAddTable()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim exportLocation As String
    Dim exportFile As String

exportLocation = "xxxx"
exportFile = exportLocation & "\yyyy.csv"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("ToBeAdded")

Open exportFile For Output As #1

Do While Not rst.EOF
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Call AddTable(rst!Acces_table_name, rst!Source_table_name)
        rst.MoveNext             
        Print #1, "Succes: " & rst!Acces_table_name & vbTab & rst!Source_table_name
Loop

Close #1

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Print #1, "Failed: " & rst!Acces_table_name & vbTab &     rst!Source_table_name & vbTab & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
   Resume Next
End Sub

Sub AddTable(AccessTableName As String, SourceTableName As String)
    ' we will need to create this table using DAO
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    ' Some variable to make the code more generic
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim strNameInAccess As String
    Dim strNameInSQLServer As String

    ' set the connection string
    strConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={xxxx};Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;Dbq=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

    ' specify the tables you want to link. The table can be
    ' known by a different name in Access than the name in SQL server

    strNameInAccess = AccessTableName
    strNameInSQLServer = SourceTableName

    ' Create a table using DAO give it a name in Access.
    ' Connect it to the Source.
    ' Say which table it links to in Source.

    Set tdf = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(strNameInAccess)
    tdf.Connect = strConnectionString
    tdf.SourceTableName = strNameInSQLServer

    ' Add this table Definition to the collection
    ' of Access tables
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf

End Sub
```

Log file shows first the table as succes and next line it shows same table with failed, if an error occurs.:

```
"Succes: SOURCETBL_VALUE    SOURCETBL.VALUE"
"Failed: SOURCETBL_VALUE    SOURCETBL.VALUE 3011    Description."
```

Comment: Success or failure actually occurs in AddTable procedure. Make it a function that returns a value to CallAddTable that indicates this outcome. Output appropriate message depending on indicator. So an error handler is needed in AddTable. Why do you print to a text file?

Comment: Or leave it a Sub and do message output from AddTable with its error handler.

Comment: @June7 never thought of it that way, will adapt code to ErrorHandler in AddTable function. I use text file because that's familiar to me. Have never used reports jet. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You need permanent documentation of this outcome? Could save the result to a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, changed the code so the errorhandling takes place within the AddTable function. Now only one line per added table is written to the .csv-file.